# Short detective story. Criminals are cloned, then killed by the victims of crime for revenge

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, clones

The story is about a detective talking to different people trying to gather information about a clone. The story deals with clones of a criminal who committed murders, and they make exact clones of the criminal so the families of the victims can kill the clones to feel they got revenge.

Comment: Why are the clones being created? Is it in order to have enough entities of the murderer for *each relative* of the victim to kill *one of them*? Or are they created in order to kill *only* the clone(s) while still keeping the original murderer alive (so he can do time in jail)?

Answer (score 5):

I found the name of the story! Here is the description of it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macs_(short_story)):

> "macs" is a sci-fi short story by Terry Bisson, published in 1999. The story consists entirely of dialogue between several people and an investigator. The people are telling the investigator about clones that were used to satisfy the Victims’ Rights Closure Settlement – wherein people get a clone of the person who was responsible for the death of their loved ones. "macs" won the 2000 Locus award and Nebula award for Best Short Story. It was also nominated for the 2000 Hugo award for Best Short Story.

Comment: Congrats! You can accept your self-answer in about 25 hours by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. How did you find it?